# My python version is 3.8.5 when i am doing pip install tensorflow various conflicts has been arised

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, tensorflow2.0

My python version is 3.8.5 when i am doing this in spyder

```
pip install tensorflow
```

it shows error shown below

```
(base) C:\Users\Akanksha-Lab-PC>
(base) C:\Users\Akanksha-Lab-PC>UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
'UnsatisfiableError:' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or 
base) C:\Users\Akanksha-Lab-PC>to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:
'to' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: Are you trying to execute `UnsatisfiableError:` from terminal?

Comment: yes i am doing programming in spyder so i am running this command in anaconda prompt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information you give is very little ... So my suggestion is :

Uninstall all your python and anaconda .

Check your systen path and delete all python and anaconda.

Install latest version anaconda .

Comment: yes i have installed latest version... after installing latest version then i install python when i run python --version then it show python -3.8 when i am going to uninstall this it shows it will affect other files too .... i will try again that you have said and then will let u inform about that